# No AppID in new PayPal API?

Tags: paypal

In old sandbox/real accounts there was an AppID which one can easily get from the sandbox accounts. But in new API there is no such field. So i think its deprecated or either no more required.

Please advise would it effect the workflow if we leave it blank with the new PayPal REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. There is no AppID with the new REST API's.
Note: The AppID was only used for Adaptive API's and was available via www.x.com > My account > My apps. This still exists.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But as the PayPal has changed its sandbox structure, i am not able to test my adaptive api workflow without actual paypal account. Can you please tell any work around ? or changes which i will have to do to make it work (As my client and i are unable to login for payment using real and sandbox accounts)

Comment: you need any paypal account (personal or business) just to sign in to developer.paypal.com. Once you signin, click on Applications tab, and then Sandbox accounts link on the left nav. You can create test sandbox business account, using which you can test your adaptive payments api workflows.

Comment: Thanks. It did work. But new system is quite complicated as one needs real accounts and relevant test account in it to change the credentials for the test accounts while handing it over to the client or some other developers.